# How can I catch unexpected error messages during Cypress test execution?

Tags: cypress

I am using Cypress and iziToast (http://izitoast.marcelodolce.com/) to run some tests on a web application.
I spotted an unexpected error message whilst running it locally.
I was able to catch it by adding the following cy.toast statement to my code:

```
cy.get(tabbedPanelControlsTitle)
    .should('have.value', 'Teams')
    .click();
// this is causing the following unexpected error
cy.toast({
    type: 'Error',
    code: 'E1527360562',
  });
```

I was able to get it to fail here using the following:

```
cy.wrap({ toast: 'Error' })
    .its('toast')
    .should('eq', 'Success');
```

What I would like to know is there any way of catching these unexpected errors?

Toast Message:

[image]

Failing that, can I get the Network response to my click() command?

Comment: What is `cy.toast`?

Comment: cy.toast comes from iziToast  (http://izitoast.marcelodolce.com/). cy.toast({
        type: 'Success',
      }); checks the toast message type equals 'Success'.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the below code. This snippet will help you to catch the exception in the cypress test flow.

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    console.log("err :" + err)
    console.log("runnable :" + runnable)
    return false
})
```